# "Waiting for review" status after twice rejected

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Very strange thing goes on app review. First I did upload new version binary, then it was rejected by apple because they not found "Restore purchases" feature. I explained what app actually have this feature. Apple approved my explanation and continued review process, but then rejected app again. Reason is app icon, that is approved in previous versions. Apple provided me "Upload new metadata" button to fix my icon. After some time, application moved from "Rejected" state to "Waiting for review".

What should I do in this case? Reject binary and upload new metadata, then wait at least on week, or do nothing and wait for review now? Have you any idea?

Comment: This is probably a better question for someone on Apple's dev forums, or perhaps even http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your app is waiting for review. Just wait.

Comment: But app is rejected. After that I have not had time to make changes. Then app moved to waiting for review without my actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem about two years ago and finally my app was released to AppStore. All was solved through Apple center resolution conflicts. My app had been rejected and suddenly was set to waiting for review, in review and finally released.

Comment: It depends...for me it was about 4 days